# How to disable duplicate calendar notifications?

Tags: notifications, calendar, 4.2-jelly-bean

My stock Nexus 4 (4.2.2) is giving me multiple calendar notifications every day.  It gives me one notification which is a reminder for a specific upcoming event, and it gives me a second notification which is sort of a general roll-up of upcoming events.

Here's an example of the two notifications:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image to enlarge)</sup>

I rely heavily on the reminder notifications, but I find the rollup to be useless for me.  I've verified that both are coming from the Calendars app by long-pressing on the notifications and clicking on App Info.

How do I disable the second "roll-up" calendar notification?

Comment: When you click on the "roll-up" calendar notification what app opens?

Comment: Do you really have "Feed dog" as a calendar event!? :)

Comment: @ZnewmaN When I click on the roll-up, I get a dialog filling most of the screen called "Calendar notifications" with a scrollable list of upcoming events.  When I click on the reminder, I go directly to the specific event in the calendar app.

Comment: @w3d My dog has no opposable thumbs so he has trouble entering these reminders into his own phone.

Comment: @emmby can you post a screenshot of the screen that you get when you click on the rollup notification?

Comment: The roll-up dialog looks like this: http://cl.ly/image/0N021u0Z0Z3r

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm that this is normal behaviour for the default (blue) Google Calendar on the Nexus 4 - just the 1 app. Having tried a few tests of my own...

[image: Multiple Calendar Notifications]

The multiple "roll-up" events appear to be events for which you have already received a notification, but have not explicitly acknowledged or "dismissed" it - in which case the notification remains in the notification area and forms this group when the next notification occurs.

In the screenshot above, a notification has just occurred for "Test3", while notifications have already occurred for "Test1" and "Test2", but I did not acknowledge/dismiss them. I could, for instance, tap on the "roll-up" and dismiss "Test2" - it will then be removed from the notification area.

The only way to stop this roll-up of events is to either:

- Dismiss the notification as it occurs.
- Don't set a notification for these events.

Comment: Instead of turning off notifications for events just disable pop-up notifications in the Calendar app (which are what's being queued in the roll-up mentioned by @emmby) here: `Settings > General > Notifications and Reminders > Pop-up notification`.

Comment: I already have `Pop-up notification` disabled (which I believe is the default option) and I get the same roll-up of notifications. However, the Pop-up notification is different... you get an obtrusive pop-up when the notification occurs and you seem to get no option but to acknowledge/dismiss it, at which point it is removed automatically from the notification area. So, in fact, _enabling_ pop-up notifications would prevent the roll-up, since you are forced to acknowledge them.

Answer (score 8):

There are likely two calendar apps on your system. Stock Android includes an app and Google provides one as well, which might be preinstalled on your device, or you may have downloaded it without realizing it. They both look very similar (which is probably why you thought they were the same when you held on them for the App Info screen). Check in your app drawer. The stock Android calendar is a green calendar icon, and the Google one is blue. Then disable notifications for one of them.

You can always click on the roll-up notifications and when that app opens, go into the settings and disable notifications. Then go to your app drawer and check both icons (both are labeled calendar) see which app has notifications disabled. Once you determine what app it is, if it is the Google Calendar, you could just uninstall it, or if it is the built-in one, you can disable it via Settings -> Apps -> All -> Calendar -> Disable.

Comment: An easy check for your theory would be: follow one of the notifications, and disable notifications for the app turning up as source. Wait for the next event and see if both notifications are gone, or one remained :)

Comment: I also have a stock Nexus 4 (4.2.2) and I only have a blue Google Calendar - there is no (stock) green calendar. The same for my ICS tablet (both the same version). AFAIK the blue Google Calendar in the Play Store _is_ (or at least is now) the stock Android Calendar. If I ever had the green stock calendar on my tablet it has been automatically replaced with the blue one (via the Play Store).

Comment: Long-pressing on the notification should give you a link to "App Info", which will at least tell you which app is raising which notification.

Comment: Apparently Google replaced the stock Android calendar app (the green icon), with their proprietary calendar app (the blue icon). They did the same with the browser and put on Chrome. The Google calendar app and Chrome are not part of AOSP, but apparently, Google replaces the stock ones with their versions on newer builds.

Comment: i verified using App Info that both notifications are coming from the same app.  Calendar version 201212060

Comment: I was experiencing similar behaviour on my Galaxy S3. Been bugging me for months and I finally overcame inertia, found this question, and confirmed there were indeed two apps showing notifications. Google Calendar, which I want, and S Planner, which I don't. Turned it's notifications off and no I just get one. Much better!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the calendar app that I do (which I believe is the stock Android calendar app that has a pink icon),

- Click the icon to open the app,
- Click settings
- Then mine has a "Set Alerts & Notifications" where I can select from 3 options: (1) Alert, (2) Status Bar Notification, or (3) Off.

I use the stock calendar which uses my Google calendar and I also use Nudnik reminders app. So all three of those apps have settings for notifications that I have to consider.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So to complete your answer: You obviously have turned off notifications and alerts in all calendar apps, and have [Nudnik Calendar Reminders](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=amProgz.nudnik) deal with them, correct? That would match what I did, just that I've used [Calendar Event Reminder (CER)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.foobarsoft.calendareventreminder).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the BLUE Google calendar and want to stop getting 2 notifications do as I do:

I went into the Stock Android Calendar (Pink) & in Settings checked the Play Notification Sound Box, picked my Notification Sound & then **UNCHECKED** every other box for these settings.

Then I went to the BLUE Google Calendar & General Settings. In Notifications & Reminders I checked the Notifications Box, picked my sound so that it is the Same one as the Stock Calendar one I chose earlier & decided to check the box to vibrate & I checked Pop-up Box.

Then I **UNCHECKED** the the **MAIN Notifications Box** leaving the other boxes checked but greyed out.

**If you leave the MAIN Notification Box checked as well you will get 2 pop-ups!**

Answer (score 0):

I also had duplicate reminders on my phone (and watch) and tried out a few suggestions here. I indeed had 2 calendars in my app drawer - Google Calendar (blue) and the other (blue-green) was actually part of Boxer, which I use for multiple mail accounts. I turned off everything I could find in Boxer and now back to only one notification per event.  Why would Boxer add this to their app **with notifications turned ON** is anyone's guess.  If this even provides help to one person, I'm happy to have helped.